# Cantor ternary set expansion

Tags: cantor-set

Assume that $C$ is the intersection of all of $C_i$'s where $i\in\mathbb{N}$. $C_0=[0,1]$, and $C_i$ is obtained by removing the middle 1/3 of each inverval in $C_{i-1}$.

On an intuitive level I can see how $C=\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{3^n}\mid a_n\in\{0,2\}\}$. But how I can prove it?

Comment: How about first working with the digit $a_1$.  Show every element of $C$ has a base $3$ expansion with $a_1=0$ or with $a_1=2$.

Comment: Using your definition, note that every *finite* sum of the form $$\sum \frac{a_n}{3^n}$$ is in C. Since C is closed, the infinite sum should also be in C

Comment: How does $C$ being a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ lead to the conclusion for the infinite case? It doesn't quite look like compactness theorem (unless we can show that $C$ is well ordered).

Answer (score 1):

General idea behind a proof: Consider the ternary (i.e. base $3$) expansion of all the numbers removed in the first iteration. Do you see something they have in common? How about in the second iteration? Keep going. If we remove all such numbers, which are we left with?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I can see that $C$ does not contain the middle 1/3's of each interval, or rather $C$ contains every limit point of each open interval  that is removed.

Comment: The first iteration removes everything between $\frac13$ and $\frac23$. If you have a number written in ternary, how can you tell whether it's contained in that interval?